# Connection failed Error: "WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed" in WebSocket using PHP, JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I am currently learning to implement Websockets using PHP and JavaScript in the client side. I received connection failed error in the browser console:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed

I am new to websockets and could not find out the reason of connection failure. The online materials were not found to be helpful, so I decided to post a question here. Your Suggestion, Tips, Troubleshooting will be appreciated.

Javascript: *client.html*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var conn = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080'); 
 conn.onopen = function(e){
  console.log("Connection established");
 };
</script>
```

PHP: *server.php*

```
<?php
 $host = "127.0.0.1";
 $port = 8080;
 $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Not created');
 $result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Not bind');
 $result = socket_listen($socket,3) or die('Not listen');
 do
 {
  $accept = socket_accept($socket) or die('Not accept');
  $msg = socket_read($accept, 1024);
  $msg = trim($msg);
  echo $msg;
  echo "Enter reply";
  $reply = fgets(STDIN);
  socket_write($accept, $reply, strlen($reply));
 }while(true);
?>
```

Comment: `wss` ... so you're using secure connection - can't see where that is being set up in PHP

Comment: Save yourself a lot of heartache trying to get PHP to properly work as a Websocket Server and implement a Node.js version - it is so, so much more reliable and robust ( in my experience anyway )

Comment: A websocket is not just a simple socket. There's a whole protocol to implement. Not sure where you got the idea that only this basic PHP socket would do the job. There are plenty of examples online

Comment: @JaromandaX I dont know is there any settings in PHP. Have to check if any. I have just only enabled sockets in php.ini.

Comment: do you know the difference between `ws` and `wss` ... similar to `http` and `https` ... ever written a HTTP**S** server in PHP? - edit: nevermind, people don't write actual servers in PHP - forgot what language I was talking about

Comment: @ADyson Have heard about ratchet. But, I want to implement with pure javascript & PHP, without any third party library.

Comment: You enjoy making your life hard for yourself? Or is it because you are keen to learn the details? Nevertheless, if you want to do that, you need to actually understand [the websocket protocol](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455) before you start to code. And [there are still examples online](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+websocket+server), without libraries necessarily. What you've posted in your question suggests you did not do any proper research into how websockets actually work.

Comment: @ADyson I did a little bit of research (theory only) in websockets, but no practical knowledge in it. I have posted only a fraction of my code here. Although I can use a third party library (like ratchet), I am keen to learn the details. Also, I think of any issue during deployment in a real server, if I use any third party app (regarding support from web hosting servers for such third party app etc).

Comment: You need to choose carefully where you host your service. Because a lot of basic hosting providers won't let you run something like a websocket server, because it requires an extra process running continuously in the background to listen for messages, additional to the regular webserver (which they normally provide for you). You might need your own VPS or cloud-based solution. Traditional low-cost shared hosting may not work, although you can ask individual companies if they will allow it or not

Comment: `I did a little bit of research`....I think not very much, maybe, because the PHP code you've posted shows no understanding at all of what is required. It's not even close.

Comment: @ADyson you are right. Actually, I am in hurry in the process.

Comment: @ADyson Actually, I am going to integrate a real-time notification system (using websocket) in my website under construction. For that, do I need my own VPS or a traditional web server will do that for me? I have no idea.

Comment: Well like I said, it depends what the hosting account you buy will support. You will certainly need a webserver for the regular website part, but all hosting, including shared hosting, will provide that. The websocket server needs to run as an extra service though, so it depends if that is allowed on the service you are looking at buying. VPS can certainly do the job but of course it costs more. Obviously though you need more than just this one criteria when choosing hosting, you need to think about predicted capacity, scaling, support etc.

Comment: @ADyson yeah, then it seems to be a daunting task that makes me feel amazed at how companies like facebook, stackoverflow really did this..!

Comment: Well they employ lots of staff, including some who are probably experienced in the technology areas, and/or spend the time to do thorough research, and then write lots of code and do lots of testing, and probably get it wrong a few times before they get it right. It's harder to do it right when you're just one person or in a very small team, but it's not impossible. Ready-made cloud services, containerisation etc can make your life easier with hosting and scaling etc. There are ready-made websocket solutions you can just pick up and use, and they would cost very little for a small site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: Your client.html says:

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080');
```

(non secure connection) but your error message says:

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed

(secure connection attempt). Make sure to execute client.html through an insecure connection or any attempt to make an insecure WebSocket connection will fail.

You will also receive the "WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8080/' failed" error message if the connection to the PHP server is lost before the handshake is complete or receives something other than the response for the handshake. Only after the handshake is complete "conn.onopen" will fire.

Try the following server.php (based on your code)

```
<?php

class WebsocketHelper {
    public static function parseHeadersFromRequest(string $request) : array {
        $header_values = [];
        $header_lines = explode("\r\n", explode("\r\n\r\n", $request)[0]);
        foreach($header_lines as $header_line) {
            $key_values = explode(":", $header_line, 2);
            $header_values[trim($key_values[0])] = empty($key_values[1]) ? null : trim($key_values[1]);
        }
        return $header_values;
    }

    public static function createAcceptFromKey(string $key) : string {
        $key .= '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
        $key = sha1($key, true);
        return base64_encode($key);
    }

    public static function createResponse(string $accept_hash) : string {
        $response  = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\r\n";
        $response .= "Upgrade: websocket\r\n";
        $response .= "Connection: Upgrade\r\n";
        $response .= "Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {$accept_hash}\r\n";
        return $response . "\r\n";
    } 
}

$host = "127.0.0.1";
$port = 8080;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0) or die('Not created');
$result = socket_bind($socket, $host, $port) or die('Not bind');
$result = socket_listen($socket,3) or die('Not listen');

$accept = socket_accept($socket) or die('Not accept');
$msg = socket_read($accept, 2048);

$msg = trim($msg);
echo $msg . PHP_EOL;

$headers = WebsocketHelper::parseHeadersFromRequest($msg);
$accept_hash = WebsocketHelper::createAcceptFromKey($headers['Sec-WebSocket-Key']);
$reply = WebsocketHelper::createResponse($accept_hash);

socket_write($accept, $reply, strlen($reply));

sleep(10);
socket_close($socket);
```

I've started server.php in Terminal and navigated to client.html in Chrome. The server output showed:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
Connection: Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Upgrade: websocket
Origin: http://me.local
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Sec-WebSocket-Key: mNxSdACO2fkrhzvaemT9Aw==
```

and the console in Chrome showed:

> Connection established

Comment: What does WebsocketHelper class do? Where from its methods are called?

Comment: @ParveezAhmed `Where from its methods are called`...just read further down the code... And the purpose of the class appears to be to create a re-usable set of functions which can respond correctly to websocket messages.

Comment: @ADyson is exactly right, the WebsocketHelper class provides functions needed for the opening handshake. Referring sections 1.2 and 1.3 of the standards track of the websocket protocol: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6455#section-1.2